# How to watch JMX Mbeans

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

jconsole requires GUI which does not work under terminal. Any tools I can use in the terminal to retrieve JMX information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm).